Under what kind of conditions is the following matrix non-singular?
Given $m$ complex numbers $z_1,\ldots,z_m \in \mathbb{C}^m$, I am interested in the singularity of the following $2m \times 2m$ real matrix
\begin{equation}
M := \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\Re(z_1) & \cdots & \Re(z_m) & \Im(z_1) & \cdots & \Im(z_m) \\
\vdots & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
\Re(z_1^{2m-1}) & \cdots & \Re(z_m^{2m-1}) & \Im(z_1^{2m-1}) & \cdots & \Im(z_m^{2m-1})
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
I want to know under what conditions is $M$ non-singular (i.e., full rank)?
Any hint is appreciated. Thanks!

Is there a reason to believe there would be a significantly easier criterion for this kind of matrix than "the determinant is $\neq 0$"? I mean for real or purely imaginary $z$, theanswer is trivial, and something looks a bit like a Vandermonde matrix, have you tried something with that?

I have been thinking the Vandermonde technique, but I did not managed to find any useful tools to analyze the Singularity of the real part of the Vandermonde matrix.
